# Add a Bootstrap popover to a bootstrap-select picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to add a pop-over to a Bootstrap-select picker, but the results are finicky. How can I do this reliably?

Thanks.

### Code

I have a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wotasoneso/1/edit?html,js,output) of the code. Here are the relevant excerpts:

#### Html

```
<body>
  <input class="" type="text" id="text" />
  <select id="select">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option1</option>
  </select> 
</body>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$("#select").selectpicker({selectOnTab: true, title: "My Title"});

$("button[data-id='select']")
//$(".bootstrap-select")
  .popover({title: "test", content: "test2", trigger: "focus", container: "body"});
```

## Problems

If I use `button[data-id='select']` as the selector, then it sort of works, but

- The popover disappears when a drop-down menu item has focus, since the drop-down menu is not contained within the button.
- The `title` setting of the popover gets overwritten by the `title` setting of the select picker. (It looks like they are using the same field on the `<button>` DOM node.)

On the other hand, if I use `.bootstrap-select` as the selector, it works flawlessly, but only when one select picker is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the select in a div and reference the div instead.

#### HTML

```
    <body>
    <input class="" type="text" id="text" />
    <div id="pop" style="display:inline-block">  
     <select id="select">
         <option>option1</option>
         <option>option1</option>
      </select> 
    </div>
    </body>
```

#### Javascript

```
$("#select").selectpicker({selectOnTab: true, title: "My Title"});   
$("#pop").popover({title: "test", content: "test2", trigger: "focus"});
```

- Be sure to use `style="display:inline-block"` on the div otherwise the div will fill the screen instead of the width of the select.
- By using a wrapper div you won't have the title problem.

link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/letecaxafu/edit?html,js,output